# Delete for placement or non-placement new

Tags: c++, memory-management, destructor

Does anyone know a C++ delete procedure that is safe for both placement new and for regular new?

```
Object* regular = new Object();
delete_procedure(regular);

void* buf = ::new(sizeof(Object));
Object* placement = new(buf) Object();
delete_procedure(placement);
```

This function seems to work, but I can't figure out if it's actually safe for both instances (it's the standard method of deleting placement new).

```
delete_procedure(Object* obj){ // Not sure if safe for regular new
  obj->~Object();
  ::delete(obj);
}
```

Comment: In case you care: Why do I need this?  I'm writing a garbage collector for concurrent data structures and some objects the GC manages may be effectively variably sized via placement new for efficiency (e.g. metadata followed by c string), some objects might not be, and I'd prefer to not rely on the user to keep track of the difference.

Comment: No such procedure can exist, since you must match the `delete` with the corresponding `new`, and moreover, there is no "placement-delete expression".

Comment: Always use placement new?

Comment: Note: if `delete_procedure(p)` is safe then `delete p;` is necessarily also safe. The unsafety would stem from a `new` expression allocating more than `sizeof(T)`. If that's not a problem on your platforms you're good to go. Note: the code you show for allocation + construction is leaky. Also, it should use `::new`, not unqualified `new`, unless you want to possibly pick up an allocation function from the `Object` class.

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe there's any unified way of doing this without introducing some extra flags to mark things. The C++ philosophy is "you need to keep track of how you allocated things and ensure they're all destroyed properly," and it does this for efficiency purposes. Think about `delete[]` versus `delete`. There could be a unified `delete` keyword that cleans up any block of memory, but that would incur a performance overhead because of the cost of determining which deallocation routine needs to be invoked. Or think about virtual destructors: C++ could say that `delete` always does some kind of type introspection, but that would add overhead to all object types, much of it unnecessarily.

C++'s philosophy is "don't pay for what you don't use," and so if you want to build something unified, you'll need to set up some extra infrastructure to track what sorts of deletion routine you need to do.

Comment: I would be surprised if there is any platform where flags are necessary, provided that the allocation expression is fixed. Note that this is an in-practice question, not a language lawyer question. Anyway this answer is a comment, expressing your belief and some advice about what to think about, not an answer, so, flagged as such.

Answer (score 1):

No, because of arrays and details.  Sure, because these problems probably don't matter in your code base.

All deletes are either type specific deletes, or:

> The behavior of the standard library implementation of this function is undefined unless ptr is a null pointer or is a pointer previously obtained from the standard library implementation of operator new(size_t) or operator new(size_t, std::nothrow_t).

from http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_delete

This means passing memory allocated by `new[](size_t)` to `delete(void*)` is UB, and `new[](size_t)` to `delete[](void*)` is UB.

---

Second, users are free to replace new/delete on a global or per-class basis.

---

Third:

```
void delete_procedure(Object* obj){
  obj->~Object();
  ::operator delete((void*)obj);
}
```

you'll want to cast to void pointer there and use operator delete.

---

Forth, the pointer passed to `delete_procedure` must be the pointer generated by `new T` or `::new( ::new(sizeof(T)) ) T`; it cannot be a pointer to a derives subobject, as its value as a `void*` may differ.

If `T* pt` is dynamic castable, `dynamic_cast<void*>( pt )` will reconstruct that `void*`.  So this is less of a barrier than it seems.  Remember to do the cast before destroying the object!

```
void delete_procedure_dynamic(Object* obj){
  void* ptr=dynamic_cast<void*>(obj);
  obj->~Object();
  ::operator delete(ptr);
}
```

and use SFINAE/tag dispatching to dispatch between the dynamic and non-dynamic versions.

---

Fifth, high alignment types need work to handle.  They use different new and delete.  I am uncertain how dynamic casting and over aligned derived types would interact, but probably you don't have to care.

---

But `new T` calls ``` ::new(size_t)`` then constructs an object there. ```operator delete(void*)`must be fed memory produced by`::new(size_t)`.  Destroying an object creates by`new T`is legal via`.~T()`.  So I see nothing fundamentally broken.

In practice, what I might do is override "normal" new to follow the same pattern as your extra storage new (and allocate the block via `new(size_t)`) to keep things simple.  You are in arcane territory, why not make things uniform.

Comment: Could be marginally even better by mentioning `dynamic_cast<void*>` to get at complete object. Oh, and exception safety. I think the OP posted pseudo-code, I can't see how that could compile.